what is + symbol on an elevation on a chart of controlled airspace?
what does this + symbol mean?It is depicted in Miami class B area and +10/70


It means that the class B starts above 1000 feet- that is, at exactly 1000 feet you are outside the class B but at 1001 you are in the class B.
Without the +, 1000 feet would be in the class B.

Why? What difference does that make?

I am no expert of aeronautical charts, but you have to draw the line at some point. I imagine that in general it is easier to plan/flight at 1000ft rather than strictly below - imagine if you have to give clearance "up to 1000 ft" or "at 1000 ft" versus 999ft or whatever.

That seems like a ridiculous and unnecessary distinction, because who is going to fly at 1000'?  Or 999' for that matter?

@Mormegil One foot, typically.

Haha, so technically, if a GA pilot flew exactly at 1,000 ft she could be legal?  1 foot below class B and 1 foot above busting FAR 91.119.  Nope, just stay outta there!

@AeroAndy Most of that shelf is over open water so you're fine by 91.119 as long as you're not within 500 feet of a person, vessel, vehicle, or structure. Not that I'd want to fly that low over open water unless I were in a seaplane!

Good point @Chris. On a related note, reminds me of some fun, but not so wise, times years ago between Long Beach and Catalina Island...
